Windows virtual machine cannot ping Ubuntu virtual machine successfully in virtualbox using ipv6
In virtualbox, I open two virtual machine, one is windows10 ,another is Ubuntu22,both network pattern is NAT network, and windows's static IPv6 address is fc00:1337::19, Ubuntu's static IPv6 address is fc00:1337::17, now the ubuntu system can ping windows system successfully, but windows cannot ping Ubuntu successfully, can someone give some solutions
I expect the windows virtual machine can ping Ubuntu virtual machine successfully using Ipv6 address

and the ipv6 prefix of both is 96 ,means windows virtual machine is fc00:1337::19/96, ubuntu virtual machine is fc00:1337::17/96

Might the Windows Firewall be  blocking ping: https://www.interserver.net/tips/kb/enable-and-disable-icmp-ping-in-windows-10-firewall/?
